# sem_open for named semaphore fails as my process is not able to create related files in /dev/shm

Tags: linux, semaphore, shared-memory

I am trying to create a named semaphore for my processes. However, when I run my process it gives error "sem_open: No such file or directory". I checked in /dev/shm and there were no files related to named semaphore are formed. 
However, If I use the same code for writing a sample program and run, it successfully creates files related to the named semaphore. And after this, when I run my actual processes, they also run successfully, maybe because the other sample process has created the named semaphore files in /dev/shm. I am confused why my actual processes are not able to create the files in /dev/shm while the sample processes are easily creating.

I have used following code for creating semaphores:

```
#define SEM_MUTEX_NAME "/sem-mutex"
#define SEM_BUFFER_COUNT_NAME "/sem-buffer-count"
```

At semphore creator process:

```
mutex_sem = sem_open (SEM_MUTEX_NAME, O_CREAT, 0660, 0)
buffer_ready_sem = sem_open(SEM_BUFFER_COUNT_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 0)
```

At other process:

```
mutex_sem = sem_open (SEM_MUTEX_NAME, 0, 0, 0)) == SEM_FAILED)
buffer_ready_sem = sem_open (SEM_BUFFER_COUNT_NAME, 0, 0, 0))
```

Can it be related to the permission of the process to create semaphores and related files in /dev/shm? If yes, how do I check and change the permissions?

Comment: Please delete your question for now and first extract a [mcve] from your project. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: It is suspicious that that you create semaphores with mode 0644, as any users of a semaphore must be able to both read and modify it.  Modes 0666, 0660, and 0600 are the only ones that make much sense for semaphores.  But that probably does not explain the problem.

Comment: I think you're saying that your attempts to open a semaphore fail in one program, but succeed in a different one whose code is derived from the first.    Excellent!  You have taken the first steps to producing a [mre].  To continue that process, try intermediate codes between the original non-working code and the working example.  The objective is to see what you can remove from the original while retaining the failure behavior, and / or what you need to add back to the example code to break it (I'd start with the former).

Comment: Note: you should identify the source line responsible for your error message.  Be *sure*. Not only will that constitute a clue to what code you're likely to be able to eliminate and what you may need to keep, but it will also allow you to perform a sanity check on whether the message accurately conveys the nature of the problem.